# install watch app without xcode

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am sending build to client via testing services other than iTunes's TestFlight.
I am using diawi.

I can send the build of iphone application normally but how I will send the build for the watch application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A watch app is always bundled within an iOS app.

You can't create a standalone build of a watch app which gets installed directly on a client's watch.

If your watch build changes, you'd need to send a new build of the iOS app which contains the latest build of your watch app.

The client can then install that iOS build on their phone, and the latest watch build will (or can) be installed on their paired watch (depending on the preference they chose within Watch settings).